# Why am I getting arp requests from local machine?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, arp

I'm connecting wireless network (provided by apartment, so possibly quite a lot of machines connect to it) and I noticed that ARP requests from local machines send to my machine instead broadcast address. Screenshot of wireshark is below: 
[image]

Is this normal thing happening on wireless network?

Update:
And now it looks like back to normal..[image]
But I still don't get why I can see that particular host is sending ARP request to broadcast. Should I just get ARP request from broadcast address instead of seeing local host to broadcast addrress?

Answer (score 0):

ARP is used by your wifi to discover the MAC address for a given IP address. ARP requests are sent as a Layer 2 broadcast, so your PC will receive all the requests any host on the LAN segment sends. in your case, I'm guessing the sending device is running some service discovery protocol, and enumerating the services available to it.

in this case, it seems to be part of how MACs do DHCP establishment.
http://cafbit.com/entry/rapid_dhcp_or_how_do

Comment: So you are saying this is normal?.. Because that sending device sent ARP to broadcast address first and later it started to send packets to me

Comment: I'd worry about the data they are sending you, rather than the ARP. unless the network is configured to isolate hosts, there is no way to avoid every host on your local network knowing that your host exists and its MAC. what services are they sending to on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to go on here, but I would guess that someone was playing with the wireless settings.

Some wireless solutions will provide a broadcast-to-unicast conversion setting.  The reason for this is that in wireless, by default broadcast normally goes at the lowest supported data rate (often 1 Mbps, although some now default to 11 Mbps).  Unicast will go at the best data rate possible for each client.

This means that instead of sending one broadcast frame at 1 Mbps, the wireless could be sending one unicast frame per client at higher data rates.  If the wireless was able to send unicast down to clients at an average of 100 Mbps (most 802.11n solutions will allow up to 300 or 450 Mbps) and there were 10 clients, then this would actually take roughly 10% of the "air time" used by the broadcast packet.

With broadcast-to-unicast conversion turned on, you would see ARP requests as you show that are sourced from the host and destined for your machine.

With it turned off, you would see ARP requests sourced from the host and destined to broadcast.  Your machine needs to see it this way so that if it has the IP address that is being ARP'd for, it can respond to the correct host.